# Which is a better approach: to query using EventLogReader or get notified using EntryWrittenEventHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, event-log, system.diagnostics

I'm doing a project to read events written to an event log and display them. Later, I would like to add to filtering also to my project (say read only events from source : Name_Of_Some_App ). Should I use [EventLogReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogreader?view=netframework-4.7.2) to query for events or should I open all the log files and assign an [EntryWrittenEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.entrywritteneventhandler?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Does one offer more advantages than the other particularly in performance?

Comment: It is very hard to compare apples to oranges...I'm not sure how "if reading existing log entries is better than listening for new entries being created" can produce some sensible answer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov while using EventLogReader one can mention a bookmark to read from, so that only newer entries are read and the bookmark can be updated, also one can add a subscription!